# Why is "Me aburren escuchar las conversaciones de política" wrong?

Tags: gramática, conjugación, número-gramatical

I have a final in Spanish and I am going back over my old tests and correcting my mistakes. I can't seem to figure out how to do this one and am not sure if I am getting the right answer.

This is one of the sentences I was given:

> Instructions: Escribe la forma conjugada de los verbos.
>
> 1. Me _______________(aburrir) escuchar las conversaciones de la política.

I answered "aburren" because the direct object is plural, but was marked wrong.

Can someone explain why my answer is wrong so I can correct myself?

Answer (score 6):

This was a bit tricky. The correct form is:

> Me **aburre** escuchar las conversaciones de la política.

You can say:

> Me **aburren** las conversaciones de la política.

because in such case the subject is *las conversaciones de la política*, thus a plural form. However, in the example that you were given, the subject is *escuchar las conversaciones de la política*, which is singular.

Other examples would be:

> Me gusta ver el fútbol.

Or, to use an example containing a plural form:

> Me gusta ver los toros.

Comment: In both cases the subject of the sentence is the boring one. That is: 'escuchar las conversaciones de la política' or 'las conversaciones de la política' are the subjects. You are the direct object. If you were the subject, the verb should be in first person singular, like in *Me aburro*.

Comment: @rsanchez you are absolutely right, I got confused. I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: @rsanchez you are correct about the subject, but the *me* is actually the indirect object.  Note: *le(s) gusta ver el fútbol* for third person

Comment: @guifa I was talking about *aburrir*, which is transitive: *la política lo aburre*